# Getting result from a function in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am building the following stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS update_alert_system$$
CREATE PROCEDURE update_alert_system()
BEGIN

DECLARE done INT;
DECLARE link_id_var INT;
DECLARE curl CURSOR FOR  SELECT link_id FROM alert_system;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;

OPEN curl;
my_loop:LOOP 
FETCH curl INTO link_id_var;

call ignore_check(link_id_var);
call snooze_check(link_id_var);

IF done=1 THEN
LEAVE my_loop;
END IF;

END LOOP my_loop

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The problem is with the way I fetch data and put put as parameters to the two functions:

```
  call ignore_check(link_id_var);
call snooze_check(link_id_var);
```

Both functions should return me a number. Example of such function.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS snooze_check $$
CREATE FUNCTION snooze_check(link_id_in INT)
RETURNS INT READS SQL DATA
RETURN (SELECT count(*) as SUCCESSES FROM link_results WHERE link_id=link_id_in AND 

Length(anchor_match)>1);
DELIMITER ;
```

The question is how do I return the value from the snooze check function and set it into a variable in my stored procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE Result_ignore_check INT;
SET Result_ignore_check=ignore_check(link_id_var);
```